# Twitter typeahead with mysql source

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting a typeahead function with a PHP source file.

Here is my input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="test-field" placeholder="Contact"/>
```

My PHP source:

```
<?php

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . ("/../db_connection.php");
    global $connection;
    $search = $_POST['query'];
    $get = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_fname LIKE '%{$search}%'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $get);

    $json = array();
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $json[] = $rows;
    }
    $json =  json_encode($json);
    print_r($json);
?>
```

My JQuery:

```
 <script src="plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {


      // Init Twitter Typeahead.js
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substrRegex;

        matches = [];

        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
          if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        matches.push({
              value: str
            });
          }
        });

        cb(matches);
      };
    };


    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
          source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '../includes/functions/json_test.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'JSON',
              data: 'query=' + query,
              success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                process(data);
              }
            });
    }
  });

  });
```

I am able to show the results if I access the PHP file directly using: (localhost/X/XX/json_test.php?query=er) for example - Only if I change $_POST to $_GET (not sure why).
The Typeahead is not working at all. Any thing I am missing.
Thank you.

Edit:
Here is the json returned:

```
[{"contact_id":"6","contact_account_id":"38","contact_fname":"firstname","contact_lname":"lastname","contact_title":"CEO","contact_phone":"(123) 456-5885","contact_email":"user@email.com","contact_fax":"(123) 456-5885","contact_facebook":null,"contact_twitter":null,"contact_linkedin":null,"contact_is_main":"0"}]
```

Comment: what is `type: 'POST2',` in your `$.ajax`?

Comment: @Sean Typo, sorry - removed.

Comment: What field are you trying to search on in the returned JSON?

Comment: @LloydBanks contact_fname

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few problems with your code:

1. the reason you're only able to access it via `$_GET` is because you're making a `GET` request to the server.
2. when making search requests to the server, it is actually best to use `GET` requests, since you are trying to get data as opposed to manipulate data.
3. you inject directly into your search term `mysqli_query` call directly which opens you to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.
4. using `print_r` will not give JavaScript the data in a readable format.
5. Sending the data back to JavaScript without the correct headers set (`application/json`) will result in inconsistent results.

I suggest doing the following

PHP:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . ("/../db_connection.php");

global $connection;

$search = $_GET['query'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `contact_fname` LIKE '%?%'";

$results = [];

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
}

header("Content-type: application/json");

exit(json_encode($results));
```

JavaScript (inside HTML):

```
<script src="plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    // Init Twitter Typeahead.js
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substrRegex;

            matches = [];

            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    matches.push({
                        value: str
                    });
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };


    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.getJson('../includes/functions/json_test.php', {
                'query': query
            }, function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                process(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

One other thing I noticed was you had your javascript outside of script tags, yet had your script tag for the `plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js` file on the line above it. If this is indeed in a JavaScript file, you need to put it in the HTML on the page and wrap your JavaScript in `<script>` tags. Also make sure your paths are correct to the JavaScript and PHP files so it correctly loads them. It is usually better to give absolute URL's to your assets relative to the root URL, such as `/full/path/to/plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js` and `/full/path/to/includes/functions/json_test.php`

one thing which concerns me is that it appears that your `db_connection.php` file is in your webroot, which means people can visit and potentially download your `/includes/db_connection.php` file and get all your database connection credentials.

If you need any further help, let me know!

Comment: Hello Andrew, It doesn't work. I have the correct code placement. Do I have to include the json_test.php in the code via include(). ? Also getting "mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters," in line 13 of the PHP query.

Comment: see my edit regarding the `mysqli_prepare`, initially I wrote it using the OOP implementation of `mysqli`.

You shoudn't need to use `include()` in the page with your javascript as the `getJson` jQuery call loads it directly from the page.

what is the public directory structure of your project?